# Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 accesstoken, login cookie or other valid authentication credential(Googleads)

Tags: asp.net-core, google-api, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I am trying to migrate Adwords API(sunset on 27th April, 2022) to Google Ads api. Using Asp.Net Core(5.0) and c#.

Exception:
Google.Ads.GoogleAds.V10.Errors.GoogleAdsException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Status(StatusCode="Unauthenticated", Detail="Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),

I want to use "keywordPlanIdeaService"
Can anyone have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a header to your Google Ads API Http request

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

where access_tioken was returned by Google auth server.

Comment: I am sending like below format in c# . -> GoogleAdsConfig config = new GoogleAdsConfig() {
                  DeveloperToken = AdwordsModel.                                                     
                 DeveloperToke OAuth2Mode = OAuth2Flow.APPLICATION,
                  OAuth2ClientId = AdwordsModel.OAuth2ClientId,
                  OAuth2ClientSecret = AdwordsModel.OAuth2ClientSecret,
                  OAuth2RefreshToken = AdwordsModel.OAuth2RefreshToken
                  };
GoogleAdsClient = new GoogleAdsClient(config);        but Not generating the Access token